# RecyclerView and RecyclerView Adapter with a map instead of a list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and a RecyclerView Adapter with two lists and i need to switch to mutableMaps.

`itemList` holds views for displaying data and `skillList` hold `Skill` objects which contain the data.

The problem is, that there are more `views` then `Skill` objects. For example i create a Skill and that `Skill` has a id, a picture and a audio file.
For example `viewPic` displays the picture, `viewMp3` the audio file and `viewId` the id of the `Skill` object.

Reason being that the user is able to display the data on different button presses.

---

I now want to avoid the problem of not being able to bind the proper data to the right view at `position`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentViewItem= itemList[position]
        val currentSkillItem=skillList[position]
        when(holder){
            is SkillbarViewHolder ->{

            }
            is SkillTextViewHolder ->{
                //holder.add_skill_add_text_textview.text=currentSkillItem.addSkillTextCont
            }
            is SkillUploadViewHolder ->{

            }
            is SkillMicroViewHolder ->{
```

I can't find a way of binding the right data of the object to the right view because multiple `views` use the same objects data so the lists are not the same size.

This is my Adapter class
[OldAdapterclass](https://pastebin.com/uJ0axbLW)

and this is my Activity [Activity](https://pastebin.com/R59Xn3rV)

---

Now i want to change itemList into a mutableMap<index,View> and skillList into a mutableMap<index,Skill>

i want to achive something like this:

```
addBarButton()
        create var index 
        calls createSkill()
        in SkillbarAdapter createSkill() 
            creates Skill
            skillList.put(index,Skill)
        In SkillbarAdapter addSkillView()
            itemList.put(index,View)
            view.tag=“xxx"
```

If the addBarButton gets called it sets the `index +1` and with that `index` the `Skill` gets created with the key `index`. Then the view gets added to the `itemList` at key `index` so that later i can determine which view is connected to which `Skill` object. Also i can see what kind of view it is because of the tag.I hope i explained it well.

So tried to change the Adapterclass accordingly but i throws errors at the `getItemViewType` method that the `viewtype` is invalid.

[NewAdapterclass](https://pastebin.com/jQA3bJgV)

Any idea of what i am doing wrong with the maps in recyclerView Adapter??
Also i don't know how i should change the getItemViewType method.

The error is:
[Error](https://pastebin.com/iv29ZyR0)

the invalid viewtype means that something with the position oder index is wrong and the view is not properly put in the itemList or there is no view, i guess. Because i check in the getItemViewType if the item is a view or not, if not then it throws a exception.

---

update:

I have now added a default case but it is still not working. And i also not really understand why. In my addBarButton on my activity class i inflate the view and set the tag, so the tag should already be set. When then the Adapter calls the getItemView Type there should already be a view with a tag and it should return "aDD_SKILL_BAR" and in the oncreateViewHolder it can create views of each kind and sets tags when the recyclerview needs to recycle and reinflate views or am i wrong? Why it still throws the error and cannot identify the view? Before with lists it worked but i switched because of the data binding issue. Now with map it just won't work.

I tried also a different approach with a customView and identifying a view by its type as a String and casting the inflated view to a custom view but it fails because i use constraint layouts in the layouts i want to inflate.

I am new to kotlin and i never ever did something like that in a project before andi need some help to get my brain unstuck. I am out of ideas :(

Comment: Maybe expand and explain what "i throws errors at the getItemViewType method that the viewtype is invalid." means.

Comment: I tried to explain all i know in the edit

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You're doing things backwards.
You're setting view tags on your views in `onCreateViewHolder`. But you'll notice that `onCreateViewHolder` gets pass in a `viewType`. Which means `getViewType` has to get called before `onCreateViewHolder` to know what type to create a ViewHolder for. But your `getViewType` is depending on the `view.tag` property, which will not have been set, hence your error.

**Solution**

You should not be using `view.tag` as the determining factor of which type to create. By definition, `getViewType` does not know what views exist yet - that function itself is what is determining which views will be created for the given position.

You need to change it so it returns the correct view type given the list of items and the position value being passed in. That's your business logic only you know.

*Given the list of items in `skillList` and `itemList`, what type should the view at `position` be?*

---

**Update**

> In my addBarButton on my activity class i inflate the view and set the tag, so the tag should already be set.

Passing a view into an adapter manually is not how you add views to a RecyclerView. You are supposed to create it when the `onCreateViewHolder` method is called, which you seem to be doing. So you're creating two sets of Views for each item, the first of which seems to only exist to have a `tag` set on it. This does not make sense.

Google for examples of RecyclerView.

> When then the Adapter calls the getItemView Type there should already be a view with a tag and it should return "aDD_SKILL_BAR" and in the oncreateViewHolder it can create views of each kind and sets tags when the recyclerview needs to recycle and reinflate views or am i wrong?

You are wrong. Again, your code is going in circles. You're trying to set the view `tag` based on the view `type` and you set the view `type` based on the view `tag`.

> Why it still throws the error and cannot identify the view?

Your code is complicated, not following standard `RecyclerView` patterns, and has a bug.

> Before with lists it worked but i switched because of the data binding issue. Now with map it just won't work.

You probably have a bug in your indexing. You should not be using a Map to keep track of item indices. Again, this is not following standard patterns. You should have a single list of items that should be showing in the RecyclerView, not maintaining two maps and trying to keep track of indices.

> I tried also a different approach with a customView and identifying a view by its type as a String and casting the inflated view to a custom view but it fails because i use constraint layouts in the layouts i want to inflate.

OK. I don't know what that means.

> I am new to kotlin and i never ever did something like that in a project before andi need some help to get my brain unstuck. I am out of ideas :(

I would suggest you step away from the Android code then and spend some time learning and understanding Kotlin by itself. Then come back to your problem and hopefully you'll be able to tackle it with fresh eyes and new knowledge and perspective.

Good luck.

Comment: Okey, i am starting to understand the problem part. One thing i then cannot explain is, why the view part worked before. Before with the lists the view part worked but the backend Skill object part failed. Now i think the logic behind the Skill part with the maps should work (i guess) but the view part fails. I don't question your answer. The whole situation why the view part worked in the first place throws a lot of questionmarks in my brain. It should have failed in the beginning already.

Comment: Then for the solution part. I think i get what you mean. For your question. The problem is there is no populated list passed to the Recyclerview. The list is empty but the actions of the user will slowly fill it up. I am searching for a way to check what the viewtype is at position because based on that i want to inflate different layouts. The user gets a basic layout and then presses a button on the layout, then the old view in that position gets replaced by a new different one, so the view type changes.

Comment: maybe i am thinking wrong or use something wrong to achieve what i want.

Comment: Your old adapter defaults to `aDD_SKILL_BAR` (the last `else` statement). Add a `default` case to your `when` statement instead of throwing the exception if you want the same behavior.